# Android Studio hide item

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i wanna ask how do i set if my payment method is QR Payment i wanna show a QR code at the Enter cash field and and all the thing below payment method until the keypad will be hidden if it is QR Payment method. If it is Cash payment method it will show enter cash , CHANGE and the keypad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/quUTj.jpg
This is the result i want , this picture is edited with paint not coded

`PaymentActivity.java`

```
package com.tankarjian.it212n.a2910assingment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tankarjian.it212n.a2910assingment.roomDb.database.MyDb;
import com.tankarjian.it212n.a2910assingment.roomDb.database.TransactionRecord;

import java.util.List;

public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double totalPrice = 0;
    double totalTax = 0;
    private List<Product> productList;;
    Button button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6,
            button7, button8, button9, buttondecimal, buttonclear;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_activty);

        TextView et_cash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_cash);
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        buttondecimal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondecimal);
        buttonclear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonclear);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "1");
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "2");
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "3");
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "4");
            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "5");
            }
        });
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "6");
            }
        });
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "7");
            }
        });
        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "8");
            }
        });
        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "9");
            }
        });
        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + "0");
            }
        });
        buttonclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText("");
            }
        });
        buttondecimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et_cash.setText(et_cash.getText() + ".");
            }
        });


        if (getIntent() != null) {
            totalPrice = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("TOTAL_PRICE", 0);
            totalTax = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("TOTAL_TAX", 0);
            productList = (List<Product>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");
        }

        TextView tvTotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.tv_total_amount);
        tvTotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice + totalTax));

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PaymentActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        TextView etCash = findViewById(R.id.et_cash);
        findViewById(R.id.btn_calculate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String cashString = etCash.getText().toString();
                if (cashString != null && !cashString.isEmpty()) {
                    double cash = Double.parseDouble(cashString);
                    if (cash >= totalPrice) {
                        double payableAmount = cash - totalPrice - totalTax;
                        TextView tvPayable = findViewById(R.id.tv_return_amount);
                        tvPayable.setText(String.valueOf(payableAmount));
                        saveTransactionToDatabase();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this, "Please enter the cash more than amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(PaymentActivity.this, "Please enter an amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btn_history).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveTransactionToDatabase() {
        long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (productList != null)

            for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
                sb.append(productList.get(i).name);
                sb.append(" ,");
            }

        TransactionRecord transactionRecord = new TransactionRecord(sb.toString(), date, String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        MyDb myDb = MyDb.getInstance(PaymentActivity.this);
        myDb.myDao().addRecord(transactionRecord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Enter cash amount after hidden keyboard right..?

Comment: If user choose cash payment method the keyboard will show , if user choose qr payment method the keyboard will be hidden and the keyboard place will show a qr code image.
https://imgur.com/a/nEUkgd2
Something like this different payment method has different view.

Comment: Create 2 different view's for each payment mode and make them visible/gone on the basis of payment method selected.